# In Symfony how can i write images url inside javascript

Tags: javascript, image, symfony1

i want to insert image on page using javascript function

```
//JS
$('#fff').html('<img src="../images/pic.jpeg">');
```

when i write the url as above ...nothing  loaded.

How can i write correct URL ?

Comment: Use [`image_tag`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/helper/AssetHelper.php#L304)

Comment: can i write it inside js code ? And How ?

Comment: Oh I see. Nope you can't. You should have to generate the js using php or use absolute path for your image ie: `/images/pic.jpg`

Comment: For one, you didn't close your HTML tag, it should read:
`$('#fff').html('<img src="../images/pic.jpeg">');`

Comment: @PeanutButterJelly : it's not the issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the js code is in your view template, then you do do

```
$('#fff').html('<?php echo image_tag('pic.jpeg') ?>');
```

else if it is in a separate js file, you need to use the absolute path for it.

```
$('#fff').html('<img src="/images/pic.jpeg">');
```